# shutil.copy() between origin and destination with Error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, file, copy, shutil

I am copying between two folders, the source folder containing multiple subdirectories, and the destination, which is an empty folder. I'm coming up with some errors in my glob using shutil.copy():

```
def copy_files(old_dir, new_dir) -> str:
    for files in old_dir.rglob('*.xlsx'):   #iterate through directory
       if files.match("string_title"):   #filter results matching "string title"
           new_path= new_dir.joinpath(files)   #join file name to new_dir
           if Path.exists(new_path):   #if file already exists in new_dir, pass
               pass
           else:   #if file doesn't exist in new_dir, copy old file to new
               try:
                   shutil.copy(files, new_path, follow_symlinks=True)
               except OSError as e:   #if FileNotFound or other OSError, raise
                   raise e
```

I'm getting an error on a subfolder that exists on my directory, but is showing up as "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified".

Additionally, I have the following print statement results applied to my code and just above the If else statement:

```
"file is: \\user\name\origin\file.xlsx"
"new_dir is: \\user\name\destination"
"new_path is: \\user\name\origin\file.xlsx"
```

Seems like the new_dir.joinpath(files) is not working as hoped, as I was hoping to find something closer to **"\user\name\destination\file.xlsx"**

How would I change this to prevent an error?

Comment: You can print out the value of `subfolder` to see what's wrong. It's most likely you have passed in a path to a xlsx file instead of a folder to the copy function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I also thought that the name `subfolder` was too ambiguous in the question so I changed it to `file` instead. I'm now seeing that it pulls the following in print statements before the shutil.copy: `"file is: \\user\name\origin\file.xlsx"
"new_dir is: \\user\name\destination"
"new_path is: \\user\name\origin\file.xlsx"`

Comment: Considering you are running on Windows, the missing of drive letter seems strange

Comment: Maybe if I ran this in docker I wouldn't be having a problem. Unfortunately, my work computer is a Windows, and I don't have authorization to run my Mac with work stuff, which makes it harder to know if it's because it's Windows or if I missed logic on my code.